# How to change compilable static (CoffeeScript, LESS) source directory in Play Framework 2.3.1?

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.3, scala-2.11, sbt-web

I'm using Play Framework 2.3.1 and Scala 2.11.

I need to change LESS and CoffeeScript source directory from "app/assets" to "app/privateassets" for example.

How to change it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to change it by setting `sourceDirectory` for the `Assets` config (comes with sbt-web), like this:

```
import com.typesafe.sbt.web.SbtWeb.autoImport._

sourceDirectory in Assets := (sourceDirectory in Compile).value / "privateassets"
```

Comment: Thanks! But if I need to compile "app/assets" to "public" and "app/privateassets" to "protected", can I do that?

Comment: Not sure if that is possible since sourceDirectory is one File and not a list of file, I would dig into the sbt-web sources to try to figure out if there is another setting where you might list multiple files/dirs if I were you.